# I accidentally GZIPed a whole bunch of files, one by one, instead of using tar(1). How can I undo this mess?

Tags: shell, files, recursive, gzip

I'm new to the gzip command, so I googled some commands to run so I can gzip an entire directory recursively. Now while it did that, it converted each of my files to the gzip format and added .gz to the end of each of their filenames.. is there a way to ungzip them all, one by one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are essentially two options for going through the whole directory tree:

Either you can use `find(1)`:

> `find . -name '*.gz' -exec gzip -d "{}" \;`

or if your shell has recursive globbing you could do something like:

> for file in **/*.gz; do gzip -d "$file"; done

Answer (score 0):

For one file at a time you can use:

```
gzip -d file.gz
```

For multiple files you can use:

```
for i in *.gz; do gzip -d $i; done
```

Comment: I have a lot of files, so this would take way too long.

Comment: @PaulBGD , My mistake, I misunderstood "is there a way to ungzip them all, one by one?" <-- one by one.... Anyway, I've updated the answer to include multiple files.

Comment: Is there a way to make it recursive as well?

Comment: @PaulBGD can you please give an example of recursive scenario? It's not clear to me. The current for loop will extract all of the compressed files in a given folder/path.

Comment: Alright, never mind actually. Somehow it corrupted all my files. They're not text files, and they're not gzipped.

Comment: @PaulBGD Please edit your question to include the output of `file xxx.gz` where xxx.gz is the name of one of the files you inadvertantly compressed.

Comment: @PaulBGD Could you try running the `file(1)` command on them?

Comment: @PaulBGD ohh sorry to hear that :-( As a suggestion for future attempts, you can try new commands in `/test_folder/<dummy_files>` in order to prevent essential files corruption.

Comment: @Simply_Me OP said gzip and only `.gz` so what's `tar` and `.tar.gz` doing in this answer?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling you are right, edited....